# Prevent inserts to a non existing Synonym

Tags: sql-server

I have a Synonym called **VirtualTable** which points to **RealTable1**.

A lot of inserts are happening to **VirtualTable** - about 50 every second.

Very often I drop the synonym and re-create it to point to **RealTable2**.

Unfortunately it happens some times, that between the time I drop the synonym and recreate it, an insert is attempted against **VirtualTable** and I get an annoying but understandable error:

`Invalid object name 'dbo.VirtualTable'`

I tried dropping and creating the synonym in a transaction, but that doesn't make any difference. How can it encapsulate something that doesn't exist.

I know that I cannot rename or repoint a Synonym.

So my question is how I can make sure that inserts to **VirtualTable** are paused for the millisecond that it takes me to recreate the Synonym?

Or perhaps someone has a different idea of how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the synonym exists before the insert/update.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.synonyms
WHERE name = 'VirtualTable')
 PRINT 'do your stuff'
```

Comment: That would fix it functionally, but since I'm doing 50 inserts per second and rising, I am hoping to keep these inserts very simple and efficient so they are as fast as possible.

Comment: Then I guess the only way would be to stop the inserts before you drop the synonym and restarting then after you create it, all in one batch.

Comment: How do I do that? The inserts are happening from other applications, so I cannot directly stop them, but can I stop them or halt them temporarily from the database?

Comment: You could start a dummy transaction on the target tables, then the other processes should wait for it to be commited/rolled back.

Comment: But they are not hitting the target table, they are not hitting anything, because the synonym doesn't exist at the time that they call.

Comment: Good point.... Well, with my method you would have to check for the synonym in every place in your application where you call it ;/

Comment: This doesn't help anyway. Even at serializable isolation level if I do a `begin tran; SELECT * FROM sys.synonyms WHERE name = 'VirtualTable'` I am still able to go to another window and drop the synonym.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a synonym you could use a view.

Views can be the target of an insert and also support `alter` thus meaning no gap between the `drop` and `create` to worry about.